# Trying to fetch from API using multiple parameters until first success

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

So I'm trying to fetch data from an api where there's a possibility of combinations with the parameter. Here's what I worked out so far but stuck on

```
// Given a string
const drinks = 'apple juice, orange juice, strawberry juice, water';

// Create an array of each drink
const drinkList = drinks.match(/[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*/g);

let urlParamList;

drinkList.forEach(drink => {
  const splitDrinkStrings = drink.split(' ');
  let name, fruit, urlParam;

  if (splitDrinkStrings.length > 1) {
    name = splitDrinkStrings[1]?.toLowerCase();
    fruit = splitDrinkStrings[0]?.toLowerCase();
    urlParam = `${name}/${fruit}`;
    urlParamList.push(urlParam);
  } else {
    name = splitDrinkStrings[0]?.toLowerCase();
    urlParam = name;
    urlParamList.push(urlParam);
  }
});

// urlParamList = ["juice/apple", "juice/orange", "juice/strawberry", "water"]
// so the fething would look like fetch(`https://myApi.com/api/${param}`) but need to try with each param from my urlParamList until there's a success. If there's no success just throw an error.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have multiple questions here. Please stick to one question only.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of what you're ultimately expecting to hit the endpoint with (i.e., what would urlParam be). Would it just be like `/apple/juice` and `/juice/apple`?

Comment: @Tom it would be /juice/apple or /water

Comment: @trincot modified my post as per your request. Sorry for the cluster of questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few questions here, so.

The first question:

> *Best way of making this work with any number of words not just two like below?*

You can simply `join` the array, so:

```
splitDrinkStrings.reverse().join('/') // juice/apple or water or more/than/two/words
```

The second question

> *After this use each param from drinkList to try to fetch from api (`https://myApi.com/api/${urlParam}`) and stop at first success and throw an error if there's nothing?*

You could do this a number of ways you could do this, one being to use the `some` function on `Array` and if it returns false we throw an error. This code in its entirety:

```js
const drinks = 'apple juice, orange juice, strawberry juice, water';

const found = drinks.split(', ').some(async drink => {
  const splitDrinkStrings = drink.split(' ');
  const urlParam = splitDrinkStrings.reverse().join('/');

  try {
    await fetch(`https://myApi.com/api/${urlParam}`);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
})

if(!found) throw new Error('boom');
```